# how to format this json data using php

Tags: php, json

the link is [here](http://bluewingholidays.com/xxxxx.php) .please look at this bellow details and tell me how to get the value of each {} block

JSON DATA

```
 {
        "id": "1",
        "0": "1",
        "value": "Addalachchenai",
        "1": "Addalachchenai",
        "department_id": "6",
        "2": "6",
        "ordering": "1",
        "3": "1"
    }

    {
        "id": "2",
        "0": "2",
        "value": "Akkaraipattu ",
        "1": "Akkaraipattu ",
        "department_id": "6",
        "2": "6",
        "ordering": "2",
        "3": "2"
    }

    {
        "id": "3",
        "0": "3",
        "value": "Ampara ",
        "1": "Ampara ",
        "department_id": "6",
        "2": "6",
        "ordering": "3",
        "3": "3"
    }
```

PHP

```
<?php

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * FROM `jos_jea_towns` LIMIT 0, 500 ') as $row) {
       echo '<pre>' . json_encode($row, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).'</pre>';

    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

I want to get the VALUE of the joson data..

How to format above json data using php

Answer (score 2):

Use

> json_decode($jsonObject, true);

this function will convert your json data in to php array. But the code you are writing seems to be very inefficient, you should not run your queries in foreach() variables, you should use like this.

```
<?php

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db', $user, $pass);
    $result = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM `jos_jea_towns` LIMIT 0, 500 ');
    foreach($result as $row) {
       echo '<pre>';
       print_r($row);
       echo '</pre>';
       //echo '<pre>' . json_encode($row, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).'</pre>';

    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: in my json u can see lotof objects

Comment: Why are you converting your php $row variable to json if you want to use it right away.

Comment: same output will generate when we use ur code instead of my one.

Comment: Yes I know,  but when run your query in loop it get re execucted everytime

Comment: don't json_encode your $row;   json_encode will only give you a string output of php array, directly use $row variable  print_r($row); will give you your output